# PyTorch is tiling images when loaded with Dataloader

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to load an Images Dataset using the PyTorch dataloader, but the resulting transformations are tiled, and don't have the original images cropped to the center as I am expecting them.

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224),
                             transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                             transforms.ToTensor()])

dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('ml-models/downloads/', transform=transform)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)


images, labels = next(iter(dataloader))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(images[6].reshape(224, 224, 3))
```

The resulting image is tiled, and not center cropped.[![as shown in the Jupyter snapshot here][1]][1]

Is there something wrong in the provided transformation? (Image shown below on link: )
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtrIa.png

Comment: I realized that the original image and processed image don't refer to the same file in my shared code, so I checked against other files and saw this transformation is true for all files. I can update the original image in the post if necessary to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Pytorch stores tensors in channel-first format, so a 3 channel image is a tensor of shape (3, H, W). Matplotlib expects data to be in channel-last format i.e. (H, W, 3). Reshaping does not rearrange the dimensions, for that you need [Tensor.permute](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=tensor%20permute#torch.Tensor.permute).

```py
plt.imshow(images[6].permute(1, 2, 0))
```